# RecyclerView crashes when updating on top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` in my app everything is working fine I am while scrolling when the last item is visible I am adding some more item to the bottom and it is working fine. Now what the problem is that I have a `Handler` which runs after every 5 seconds and check if there is any update in the web service and if there is any update i just load the data to the top of the `RecyclerView` it works fine when I have not scrolled the `RecyclerView` but when i scroll it and the `Handler` is called(as it is called after every 5 seconds) then while updating the `RecyclerView` on the top the app crashes.

Updating function at the top:

```
public void addOnTop(ArrayList<ItemPOJO> topItemList) {
    for (int i = topItemList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        itemList.add(0, topItemList.get(i));
    }
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, topItemList.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the Error log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{419b8760 position=5 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4214)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4345)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4326)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1955)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1364)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1327)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1155)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1012)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1363)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2227)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7190)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2274)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2009)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1385)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7370)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3182)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3127)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4164)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4235)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4254)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreog
```

P.S.: `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1` is used

Comment: Just remove `notifyItemRangeInserted(0, topItemList.size());` since your `notifyDataSetChanged();` covers the notifications and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 6):

This crash might be caused by the fact that the `setViewHolder` and `onBind` methods are being called while your list(used by the adapter) is being updated, but `notifyDataSetChanged()` hasn't been called. This usually happens if you scroll through the list, or fling, while the list is being updated.

Solution:
Maintain a separate list(`tempList`) of ItemPOJOs and append the `topData` in that list.
Then clear the list used for the adapter, set the list of the adapter with the `tempList`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug of RV, see the [discussion here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77846).
In most cases, use `notifyDataSetChanged()` will avoid this crash, but it will kill Animation and Performance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
public void addOnTop(ArrayList<ItemPOJO> topItemList) {
    Collections.reverse(topItemList);
    itemList.addAll(0, topItemList);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, topItemList.size());
}
```

it's weird but in this way I resolved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling recyclerview while refreshing:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return true;
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 notifyItemRangeInserted(0, topItemList.size()-1);
```